# Disagree with a Deletion

Tags: support, moderators, deleted-answer, moderation

[This question](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/244276/f-14-in-medieval-times)

The comment from L-Dutch states:

"The first line is at most a comment to the OP's question. The rest, being based on nothing that the OP asked, is not an answer"

However, this ignores what the OP said:

"Say hypothetically, an entire American airbase with **many** extremely modern aircraft is instantaneously transported to the 1400s."

Now, my answer was to first point out that the choice of aircraft for what was being described was a poor choice - a Fleet Defense fighter (that was designed to stop Russian Heavy Bombers from getting within Anti-Ship Missile range of a Carrier group) was the wrong choice of Aircraft.

However, since the frame of the question was 'Many extremely modern aircraft' - this gives the answerer (me) scope to recommend what *would* be appropriate - which is any ground-attack aircraft  in the US Arsenal.

This gives us a choice between the A-10, the F-35, F15 Strike Eagle, Apache Attack Helicopter yadda yadda yadda - you get the picture.

In the scenario - the best choice would be an A-10, since you don't need to fly high or fast or stealthy - flying low and slow and creating as big a bang as possible is *as per the story requirements* what was needed.

Then outlining what would be the likely effects - First a dry run, then a gun run and if the Army still held their nerve, a Cluster Bomb run - which would break any medieval army's will to fight.

TL;DR - I disagree with the reason it was deleted - I think the deletee didn't read the question properly and so thought I wasn't answering the question asked. and I'm Salty and want it re-instated cause I liked that answer.

Answer (score 5):

#### You Said it Yourself

As a matter of full disclosure, I voted to close the question for being story based.

The fundamental reason that I can see for this particular answer to be closed is that it specifically doesn't answer the question, which asks about F14s, not anything else the base command could throw at the invaders.

Worse, the answer doesn't even present a [frame challenge](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7097/a-proposal-for-helping-users-understand-frame-challenges). A frame challenge *is any assertion that challenges the premise or underpinnings of a question*. The given answer says that the F14 won't be a good choice, which is a good start but does nothing to support the assertion. Yes, the answer does say that the F14 is a 'fleet defense aircraft', but what does that even mean in the context of a medieval army attack? Technically speaking, nothing in that base is designed to be an anti-mounted-knight-cavalry weapon system.

*What you're asking for won't work because of X, but you could alternatively consider Y.* If the answer had a section "because of X" that described why the F14 won't be effective against mounted knights and medieval armies then it would be a good frame challenge.

As it stands, **I'd concur that the answer was deleted properly**.

Another fairly obvious reason is the one you provided yourself as respondent:

> In the scenario - the best choice would be an A-10, since you don't need to fly high or fast or stealthy - flying low and slow and creating as big a bang as possible is ***as per the story requirements what was needed***.

By your own admission, fully aware that you're dealing with a story based question, it was technically improper to even answer the question. The best practice would be to vote to close the question and / or aske the querent to edit to make it a worldbuilding question.

That said, I am not completely adverse to answering story based questions. But they have to be really good ones! This question doesn't rise to that level in my opinion, therefore **I would be more likely to support deletion in this case than I would for a better question.**

Comment: "*... as per the story requirements what was needed.*" I'd rather say that they induced what the asker wanted to happen in the story, since we don't know the desired outcome of the battle. Still, it's a story hole we shouldn't try to fill for them ^^.

Comment: I've got no issue with the decision to close the Question - I tend not to get too involved in that side on this SE. So being charitable to the points you raised - perhaps I was a tad brief in my answer. However I don't think that mere brevity is the issue here - if the question was 'How would you use a hammer to screw in a Screw' and someone said 'You don't use a Hammer, you use a Screw Driver' and left it at that, would that be deleted in the same manner? I think not. The question left the door open for different aircraft types - to which I answered.

Comment: To answer why I didn't expand on the capabilities - Fleet Defense is a rather specialized role and is a world away from Air-to-Ground. Whilst there's no specific anti-Cavalry weaponry - there's a boatload of anti-*infantry* weaponry - which was my point. I disagree that I acknowledge that it's story based - there's plenty of good questions that say 'I need X to happen, how does that occur in my world' - to which we provide answers.

Comment: @TheDemonLord Please note that they didn't ask how to make X happen, just "what happens if I send my jets?". It's different in that the goal "X" is not stated in the latter.

Comment: @TheDemonLord --- For me, the issue isn't brevity at all. Like I said, you gave 50% of what could have been a really good frame challenge! To your example, I'd have to say yes. If you want to offer a frame challenge, I'd say there's a reasonable format in place for that! But more, *just saying* that you use a screw driver makes it more of a comment than an answer, so it could be deleted for a different reason. I do agree with you that the querent left the door open for a frame challenge. This would be a very different discussion if that were what you gave us! (cont)

Comment: (cont) I may have misspoken, but my point wasn't so much that you didn't explain *what* the fleet defense role is, but rather you didn't actually address *why* the F14 would not be a good choice. That's part of writing a frame challenge! Fair enough that you disagree about it being story based. I see that differently. As I said, I am not, in principle, against answering good story based questions; I am merely posing that as a valid deletion rationale.

Comment: @elemtilas - fair points - probably should have added a couple of lines and that's my bad - in which case though, I think a Mod Comment would be appropriate and I would happily add a few lines in an edit - which would forgo the need for deletion. As I said - I think the Deletion was too harsh.

Comment: @TheDemonLord --- No worries! As I say, you've got the makings of a reasonable answer appropriate to the question! (Story based frame challenge answer for a story based question.) And to be honest, I wouldn't have been looking for a whole book on the F14 would not be the best choice! It could be as simple as speed! When you're flying 600 or 700 mph, a battle array that's perhaps 100 or 200 yards wide might be easy to miss! I gather that they're designed for a large volume of 3D battle space. I could be wrong on that! As for "harshness" --- that's kind of a different matter! Are you (cont)

Comment: (cont) not able to see the mod's comment? If you can't, I'd be happy to edit your query here to include that!

Answer (score 5):

Allow me to use an analogy to explain what the problem was with your alleged answer.

If the questions would have been:

> Little Tommy has 10 Euros in his pocket. He is in the supermarket and he is hungry. Considering that cookies costs 1 Euro each, how many cookies can Little Tommy buy?

You answer was

> Cookies will not fill Little Tommy. He can buy a pizza tuna and onion with 6 Euro and use the change for a soda.

You just gave a little comment at the beginning of the post, and then went completely along the tangent with assumptions that were nowhere in the question.

There is no way that that would be an answer to the question, and by posting it you were bounding the OP, in case they wanted to edit the question to have reopened, to comply with your assumptions, not with their worldbuilding problem.

And for the 1000th time, "I liked my answer" it's nowhere close to be a valid reason for not deleting an answer.

Comment: So, I disagree that the assumptions I made were nowhere in the question. I quoted the *exact* part of the question on which these assumptions were built. This I feel is the crux of why I disagree with the deletion. Now, based on the discussion with elemtilas - I can accept that I should have added more context to the answer - fair enough, I could have expanded on why a Ground Attack aircraft was the correct choice, as opposed to a Air-to-Air Fighter. A Comment asking for clarification - sure. I maintain Deletion is Harsh.

Comment: @TheDemonLord Are you sure the asker wanted the U.S. to win? Are you sure that the absurdity of sending fighter planes while there's so many, so much better options there doesn't hide anything? Please give the exact references if that's the case, but as far as I see you did input some heavy assumptions which needed clarification beforehand.

Comment: @Tortliena Again, that's "a comment asking for clarification" on an answer. Maybe also a downvote if you're feeling particularly salty about it. There is no justification for deletion. And again L.Dutch justifies a deletion not by quoting the answer, but by inventing a analogy which misrepresents the answer.

Comment: @Tortliena - How did I know? Because the question wasn't 'How does my medieval army win against a Modern US Military Base?' - The asker asked about Jet Aircraft, so I answered using Jet Aircraft. I (obviously) am with JamieB here (yes, it's in my self-interest) but a comment? Sure. A request from a Mod to correct? Fine? Full deletion? too harsh.

Comment: @TheDemonLord And the question wasn't which plane/helicopter (because you quoted Apaches) was the best to win, either. It was "F-14 in medieval times?" + How effective jets would be/what would happen with jets. If it was your vision of the question, as a warfare expert you should have been struck by the question's oddness : Why planes and only them -worse, specifically F-14s- against this outmatched army? As a warfare specialist it should have raised the alarm and ask explanations before answering. You didn't and that's alright; next time you'll ask the question(s) to clear up the fog :).

Comment: @JamieB The comment asking for clarification should be for the question first, as it's the root of the issue. Now if you think L.Dutch's analogy missed the target, please read the original question and this post again like I did thrice and show exactly the big disparities. Until you can highlight them in the content and not the style, I'll just say I can't explain better than them :).

Comment: @Tortliena - I disagree with your reasoning. The F14 is cool and is famous thanks to a certain movie. But in the scenario given - the wrong choice - simply because in the US context, the F14 didn't really do Air-to-Ground. It seems I'm neither alone nor unreasonable in my view that deletion was harsh.

Comment: @TheDemonLord Perhaps, but it's again putting a lot of assumptions. You should not think everyone around the world has watched the same movie or actually anything, this very quickly leads to misunderstandings which will mislead you and others. Overall, it's actually an uphill battle for you, the only answer following you has -2 (I didn't downvote it) with only 1 upvote (I guess it's yours ^^?).

Answer (score 3):

### Don't make assumptions, ask for details instead

*Please note I don't have access to your original, deleted answer.*

> ##### Answer well-asked questions
>
> Not all questions can or should be answered here. Save yourself some frustration and avoid trying to answer questions which [should be closed]...

<sup>[How do I write good answers?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer)</sup>

Answers should reliably... Well, [answer the question to be considered as such and avoid deletion](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help/deleted-answers). As an expert in strategy, you should know that the outcomes could vary a lot because of battle circumstances and goals : If you have say 10 000 religious fanatic opponents coming from all sides and detected very late, 20 or even 50 planes wouldn't be enough to handle them just because they wouldn't have been able to take off in time. Also, the exact army compositon is not told : After the first attack, what apparels exactly are still operating? Finally, we lack the goals of the US military : If the base defense is more important than anything else, they would have gone all guns blazing from the very start and wipe out everything in a 100km area, just to be sure. But since it's not told, it could have been to avoid another diplomatic disaster, with a totally different approach (intimidation, talks...). This shows a lack of forethought from the querent on both strategic goals and context. As much as it can be entertaining, it's not your job to think that for them, as it's both dependent on what they want to tell and what they already established in their world/story. Any assumption can lead you astray from the querent's actual situation, so avoid them whenever it's possible.

I think there isn't just enough to answer the question : "What is the likelihood the jets would reach their goal (supposedly, defend the base)?". I have a checklist when people ask about strategy :

- How many forces are there exactly and which kind? What are they equipped with?
- What is their starting locations : Facing each others and far away, cornered and at close-range?
- Where are they fighting : On mountains, plains, forest, desert, asteroid field...
- What did the general chose to do? What troops are they sending, against what and for which reason? Recall that questions asking what an army or soldier would do is off-topic ([story-based](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3300/why-is-my-question-too-story-based-and-how-do-i-get-it-opened)), and questions lacking those can implicitly ask them (not the case here, but not everyone shares my point of view).
- Are there special battle conditions : Storm happening, very low morale to fight, surprise attack...?

If any of these is not described, it's likely lacking too much details to be answered without building the world and story in their stead. Ideally, the question should also focus on one individual part of the battle, as to move as much as possible individual decisions and make the resulting probabilities as accurate as possible. For instance, the question "*How well would a flamethrower tank fare against a normal one in an urban battle?*" would lead to more accurate, more objective answers than "*How well would this army of flamethrower tanks and rocket 'copters fare against this army of normal tanks and rifle soldiers in an urban battle?*".

**To sum-up, accuracy is key when asking tactic questions. If the question lacks too much details, its answers -such as yours- are more likely to miss the target.** If there's any doubt your answer would not meet the querent's needs -whether through your own observation or others-, ask for details. And remember : You're not forced to answer the question right as it gets out of the oven.

---

***Addendum from comments :** To be clear, I'm not writing here that your answer doesn't tackle the question in an absolute way, just that it's impossible to know due to the way the question is written. Guiding undecisive people towards your restricted vision of their world and intentions can be equally beneficial or nefarious to them. As such, it can balance out the [expected value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expected_value) of your answer to zero. It means effectively the answer has a too high-chance to not answer the question plus the user's needs, and so risks deletion for that reason.*

Comment: None of this really explains why an answer should be *deleted*. Deletions are for extreme wrongs and disruptions to the community. "I didn't like the question therefore I'm deleting the answer" is inappropriate for any SE site.

Comment: @JamieB Answers should... well, answer questions :). If a question can't allow answers to be struck true -which was visibly the case here, at least to L.Dutch's point of view-, then answering risk putting you at odd with the querent's actual needs. It prevents as a consequence the querent from editing their question and to improve it, in order to not frustrate you. Now if I had a look at the actual answer, I surely would have been a better judge at telling whether or not the deletion was very extreme or not, but the probability it wasn't is quite high.

Comment: Askers shouldn't fundamentally alter their questions anyway. e.g., the freeze ray guy should not go back and edit to to say "heat ray" because he decided that's what he really means. But *deleting answers* because it's *possible* that the author *might* make such an alteration to their question is rather ridiculous. We'd best not answer anything at all, by that rule.

Comment: @JamieB You're making a [caricature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Straw_man) of my point; It's an effort which needs to be made from both sides : querents accepting they can be misunderstood, answerers checking that they are aiming true. In this peculiar case study, it's likely that the querent doesn't know where to go. Giving an answer here is counter-productive to one's creativity as it could easily sway one's indecisive intentions. As you say, giving a solution answering the needs behind the question should have priority, but you have to clearly know the needs first .

Comment: Exactly why I think his answer was appropriate, or at least his description of it: sometimes answers need to guide the person in a worldbuilding process. It's still an answer. And a helpful one. Which the asker is now prevented from reading by local decree for no good reason. Answers can also take comments for improvement, so perhaps L.Dutch should have reached for the comment button instead of the extremes of deletion, which, again, should be reserved for real problems, not minor quibbles over ambiguous rule interpretation.

Comment: @JamieB No, because we don't know whether that's what they want. Check out how worlds/stories intentions change, for instance epic movies like "[RRR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RRR_(film))" or Baahubali ([great examples](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sDte-axR9l8)) vs the "serious" ones like [American Sniper](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/American_Sniper) or [Dunkirk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dunkirk_(2017_film)). We shouldn't influence our reality onto theirs even if you just want to guide them. This site is already into the "realism is always good" mood, which is not for the best :/

Comment: @JamieB Just to note, answer deletion is not just for "extreme wrongs". This answer was literally closed for "being a comment" --- a valid rationale. As far as that goes, I don't disagree with the closure. The rest of the answer was determined to be "based on nothing the OP asked for", I can understand and respect, though don't fully agree with.

Comment: @elemtilas I'm not sure why you're uncomfortable calling it what Stack Exchange calls it: a deletion. A "closure" is something that happens to questions, and means everyone can read it, but can't reply to it. A "deletion" means the bulk of users can no longer read it. The content has been hidden (both "hidden" and "deleted" are the words actually used by SE). If it wasn't done by a mod, it can be appealed via a button labeled "undelete". Seems like you're trying to edge away from what's actually being discussed here, which is *content deletion*. For some pretty thin reasons.

Comment: @JamieB --- Where did you get the idea that I'm in any way "uncomfortable"? Don't focus on typos or instances of erroneous terminology. I clearly understand the distinction, as I actually called it a deletion in the previous sentence. L. Dutch signed the comment explaining the ***DELETION***, and he's a mod, so... As for "content deletion", I was very clear in my thoughts on that.

Answer (score 3):

In support of @Tortliena's answer, and in response to @JamieB's answer (which is only his opinion)...

From the Help Center: **[Why and how are some answers deleted?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help/deleted-answers)**

> Answer posts that **do not fundamentally answer the question** may be removed. This includes answers that are:
>
> - commentary on the question or other answers
> - asking another, different question
> - "thanks!" or "me too!"-type responses
> - exact duplicates of other answers
> - barely more than a link to an external site (i.e. the actual answer is not included in the post)
> - not even a partial answer to the actual question

The exception is a [Frame Challenge](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7097/40609), but in full agreement with @Elemtilas, frame challenges are expected to be thorough. I will gladly grant that your answer did approach the intent of a frame challenge — except that the question was (and remains) so ill-prepared that the value of the challenge is entirely lost.

I could list a dozen fundamental problems with the context of the question, its purported rules of time travel, etc., not the least of which is why are we focusing on F-14s when fifty soldiers carrying XM5s and 300 rounds each could level nearly any medieval army?

But at the top of my list of complaints about the question was (and is):

> How effective will the jets be against this army, ***and what do you think what happen from then? Please explain in detail.***

Emphasis mine. That's a classic [High Concept Question](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4868/40609) and they are *off topic.*

It's not enough to expect querents to ask good questions.[[1](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask)] [[2](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)] [[3](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3624/40609)] We should also expect respondents to post good answers. [[4](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer)]

Frankly, upon review, I believe your answer violated bullets #1 and #6 of the "Why and how are some answers deleted" list and ignored the whole "answer well-asked questions" section of the Help Center. Stack Exchange's goals include being a reference library of quality questions and answers that can help more people than the first person to ask the question. From that perspective, you should have voted to close the question.

In the end, IMO, chalk it up to experience. I've had questions and answers closed, hated, and deleted. It happens. Nobody likes to hear their baby called ugly. But even if you're sure in your heart that you're absolutely in the right regarding this matter, it's more valuable to everyone that you understand the objections. Honestly, we don't need more people answering anything they come across no matter how badly the question was asked. We need people to become leaders, helping however imperfectly to improve the site's quality and service.

My point? That OP needed to be asked why the questions about F-14s were so important to him. Because I don't believe the question the OP asked was addressing the actual problem the OP was having. If I'm right, then your answer didn't help the OP at all.

Comment: Again you misinterpret the rules. You say he violated bullet #1, but bullet #1 doesn't mean your answer can't contain a comment on the question (I guarantee I can find your own answers where you do this). It just means *it can't be the whole answer*. I don't follow how you claim it violated bullet 3 in the slightest. You really need to stop arguing "letter of the law" (as if commentary on a question is entirely forbidden) and consider more what the goal of the rule actually is: to keep the site on topic and relevant, not to beat other users to death with pointless nuance and thereby damage SE.

Comment: @JamieB if we cross-reference with Elemtilas's answer, JBH probably meant more the 1st and last point of the list. A comment isn't an answer, and the rest wasn't one, either. As a whole this is not therefore an answer and the last point strikes full force :).

Comment: @JamieB I guarantee you can, too. From my answer, `I've had questions and answers closed, hated, and deleted. It happens.` You're very good at casting your own flaws onto others, BTW. Thanks, though, for pointing out an error on my part, I meant bullet #6.

Answer (score 1):

### Community Bot works as expected.

[image]
The question was closed, had no answers, and had a negative score. Such questions are routinely deleted after about one week of inactivity. If the question would be undelete, the bot would cull it within a year.

### The answer did not answer the question

The only deleted answer does not even *attempt* to discuss the actual question, backs up nothing and thus was correctly deleted.

Answer (score -4):

**Sounds like a deletion made in error.**

I can't read your answer, either (10k rep required to read deleted answers) but it sounds like your answer was appropriate and on-topic. The goal here is to help people build worlds. Helping the author understand the distinction in the types of planes that could be parked there and what roles they might play would be an important part of helping him build his world.

I think sometimes deleters get caught up on "did you answer the question directly" when they should consider "does your answer help with the fundamental worldbuilding problem", i.e., when is the question not the actual problem.

In this case, OP wants to transport a military base to the past but isn't sure what that means in immediate practical terms. He has a lot of reading to do and an answer like yours sounds like it was is exactly what he needs: not *a direct answer to his question* per se, but an understanding and a starting point of what he actually needs to build his world and a start on what reading he needs to go do. A base full of C-17s is a lot different than a base full of A-10s or AC-130s or F-15s. The answer he *needs* is help defining the boundaries.

That's worldbuilding.

Deleting content should be reserved for *egregious wrongs*. In order for an answer to be deleted, it must be completely off-topic, clearly having nothing at all to do with the question, is simply spam, or the product of a chat program.

Deleting for any other reason is inappropriate.

**I propose that the metric for deleting an answer should be similar to the metric for accepting a first time answer from the "first answers" queue.**

I think about this whenever that queue pops up, and what's my metric for deciding what to do with it.

- It's a good answer. I would upvote it. Obviously I accept these.
- It's a meh answer. I would not upvote it or downvote it. I accept these because "is it a good answer" is not the metric. We're not trying to use our opinion to screen out answers that are less than fabulous.
- It's an answer, but I disagree with it or think it needs work. I accept these, too, actually. I might accept it and then downvote it and complain in the comments *but I still accept it from the queue*. My job isn't to shut down people who write answers I think could be better. My job in that queue is to help protect the site from defacement or spam.
- It's spam, or so off-topic that it appears entirely unrelated to the OP. These I reject.

I feel like I have a pretty good system here for accepting or rejecting first time answers. It's the same metric that moderators should use for deleting answers. "Is it spam?" "Does it literally have nothing to do with the topic?" Delete. Otherwise, use downvotes and comments, not deletions.

Comment: *" Helping the author understand the distinction in the types of planes that could be parked there and what roles they might play"* it seems to me is more a matter of story than world. Knowing those things helps the author with character choice and character development. In this case, there was no worldbuilding problem to tackle, thus the deleter was more within rights than without. I personally think that it was 50% of a potentially good answer (as a frame challenge).

Comment: Story: "This base is going back in time, we need to land planes there immediately. Send X from Y squadron and Z from Q squadron!" Worldbuilding: understanding what significance X, Y, Z and Q have in the real world in order to understand how to work on your story, or if "F-14s" really even make sense to begin with. The story is what you do. The world is what you have to do it with. Sounds like the answer worked to address that, and got deleted, without breaking any rule that warrants deletion.

Comment: @elemtilas A good military base should have a wide array of weaponry type to tackle most threats in its vicinity, it's therefore not that dependent on the supreme general's decision on what it should have... Unless they're an utter idiot. If we're taking it story-wise, the story part lies in how much was left after the 1st battle, if the attackers chose/managed to damage the planes (a random choice given their lack of knowledge).

Comment: How the plane or weapon system works --- the physics and chemistry --- is a matter of world. Which actual weapons are there and what might be chosen are totally matters of story and character choice.  The answer didn't really address worldbuilding. It was literally a (good!) story building answer that dolve into tactics and what choices the respondent would take.

Comment: @Tortliena --- What happens after the first battle is even deeper into story territory! Choices of what to attack, and all of that simply makes the potential answer even worse than the question!